# Identities for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities, bernoulli-numbers

I arrived at this formula by inductive reasoning, but I don’t know how to prove it.

For any natural numbers $m$ and $k=0,1,2,\ldots, m-1$, $B_i$ - Bernoulli numbers we have:
$$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i}\cdot B_i\cdot\binom{m+i-k-1}{i}\cdot\binom{m}{m+i-k-1}=(-1)^{k}\cdot m\cdot\binom{m-1}{k}$$

Answer (score 8):

This identity can be written in the following form
$$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i+1} B_i\cdot\binom{k+1}{i}=(-1)^{k+1}(k+1).$$
The latter is equivalent to $B_{k+1}(0)-B_{k+1}(-1)=(k+1)(-1)^k$ which is one of the basic properties of Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: Thank you.
I wrote your solution in detail at 
https://dxdy.ru/post1618783.html#p1618783